# In PactBroker, When i will get the data in "Last Verified" column - New PactBroker Version

Tags: maven, pact, pact-java

**In PactBroker, When i will get the data in "Last Verified" column.**

Image : [Pact Broker - New Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hADdj.png)

Am using Maven plugin to verify with provider,

> ***mvn pact:verify***

Plugin:

```
groupId: au.com.dius
artifactId: pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11
version: 3.3.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, the JVM version has not yet got full support for this feature but we are working on it!

You can implement it yourself by following the HAL links and [publishing](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/blob/master/lib/pact_broker/doc/views/publish-verification-results.markdown) to the `pb:publish-verification-results` link.

Comment: Thanks Matthew FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you need to publish your results using `mvn pact:publish` after they've been verified so that the broker knows about them.

Comment: Nah, JVM doesn't support it yet - it's on the way though!